# I worked hard to be an altruist but SO disregarded my efforts!

Tags: support, bounties, bounty-badges

I started a bounty on [somebody else's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262474/java-fork-join-clarification-about-stack-usage) a while ago. At the end of the bounty period, I went to the question's page to award the bounty to one of the answers but it had already been attributed (100% of it).

- Has it been automatically awarded? (If that were the case only 50% would have been awarded I believe)
- Has it been awarded by the OP?
- What should I have done to be eligible for the Altruist badge? (I was excited about the idea of being an altruist - and now I feel devastated of not being one!)

Comment: Hmm, "Bounty Ended with John Vint's answer chosen by Community♦". But I thought that would make it 50%. However, the bounty was one week + 24 hours old by then, grace period expired, methinks.

Comment: It should have given you a notification 3 days and 1 day before it expired. Not sure why it appears to have given 100% of the rep though

Comment: @BenBrocka I only got one notification 23 hours before expiry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @UristMcBobby Not really - according to your link, only 50% should have been awarded.

Comment: Does anyone else think the bounty system should be far less complex? If I want to award 500 of my rep to Bob for his awesome answer to Sally's question, shouldn't I be able to just do that without the waiting period, notifications and further requirement to act? I'm not buying a gun, I'm trying to reward someone for a great contribution.

Comment: @assylias: Quote from my link: "An answer accepted during the bounty period can automatically be awarded the full bounty at the end of the bounty period, provided the bounty owner made no other explicit bounty award by the time the bounty ends."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has it been automatically awarded? (If that were the case only 50% would have been awarded I believe)

Yes, it has been automatically awarded and your assumption is incorrect.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067):

> An answer accepted during the bounty period can automatically be awarded the full bounty at the end of the bounty period, provided the bounty owner made no other explicit bounty award by the time the bounty ends.

You started the bounty on July 5. The OP accepted John Vint's answer on July 8, so it qualified for the full bounty.

> What should I have done to be eligible for the Altruist badge?

You should have awarded the bounty *manually* by clicking on the `+100` button below the voting arrows of an answer.

Comment: OK fair enough - the bounty system feels a bit like the special offer ads* (*subject to terms and conditions which are fairly complex and that nobody understands until they get caught).

Answer (score 0):

The [revisions for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11262474/revisions) contains the following text:

> Bounty Ended with John Vint's answer chosen by Community

The bounty was automatically awarded.

Only the Community user, or the user who offered the bounty can assign it; the user who asked the question cannot assign it.

As for the bounty to be fully given to the user who wrote the accepted answer, that is not what I would expect. Maybe the code that assigns the bounty was confused from the fact the answer was accepted from the OP. Basing on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/140449), given to [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) the given bounty should be half of the offered one.

> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be automatically awarded *half* the bounty amount.